# What will return when use wxDialog::ShowModal

Tags: wxwidgets

All:

I wonder what returns when I click the 'X' on a wxDialog after I call Dialog->ShowModal()?

For example:
wxDialog* Dialog = wxDialog(NULL,wxID_ANY,title,wxDefaultPosition,wxSize(310,170));
Dialog->ShowModal();

If I click the X button on the title bar, what should it return?
What if I call method like EndModal() ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click the close button, you will get wxID_CANCEL

EndModal() returns whatever value you pass to it.  http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_dialog.html#a89b6085b05b63e98001311fafcfb21f0